# Handling multiple exception types in OCaml

Tags: syntax, error-handling, ocaml

Is the following possible?

```
try
  (* danger zone *)
with Not_found e -> 
  (* code to handle not found *)
with t -> 
  (* code to handle all other issues *)
```

If I type that into the toplevel, I get a syntax error on the second `with`. Perhaps there's some syntax I'm not aware of?

Is the preferred method to prepend another `try` to match each `with`?

Comment: And what makes you think that the syntax you write should work? Have you seen it in someone's else code? Or there was such an example in manual or tutorial? Guessing is not a nice way to learn something.

Answer (score 15):

The `with` part is a series of patterns, so you can write this as follows:

```
try
    (* dangerous code area *)
with
    | Not_found -> (* Not found handling code *)
    | t -> (* Handle other issues here *)
```

Answer (score 5):

`with` is a `match` expression; you do not repeat it for multiple patterns, instead you use `|` to separate each *pattern* `->` *expression*, as with a `match`.